# Best method for returning to home screen in UWP app

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10-universal

I am developing a UWP based kiosk app, and I would like each view to return to the home page after x amount of time has passed. What would be the best method to achieve this? I was thinking of having each page start an inactivity counter and once the counter runs down to go back home. Thoughts?

Comment: With a central service for page navigation this is easy to solve. An example for a navigation service is here https://github.com/Microsoft/BikeSharing360_MobileApps/blob/master/src/BikeSharing.Clients.Core/Services/NavigationService.cs

Answer (score 1):

> I was thinking of having each page start an inactivity counter and once the counter runs down to go back home

I think that is the right way to do it.

Use `DispatcherTimer` for the counter.

To check inactivity, you can detect global input with various events on the app's `Window.Current.CoreWindow`

Touch and mouse input with `Window.Current.CoreWindow.PointerPressed`, `PointerMoved`, and `PointerReleased`.

Keyboard input: `KeyUp` and `KeyDown` (soft keys) and `CharacterReceived` (for characters generated via chords & text suggestions).

```
DispatcherTimer dispatcherTimer;

public NewPage()
{
    dispatcherTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
    dispatcherTimer.Tick += dispatcherTimer_Tick;
    dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10);
    dispatcherTimer.Start();
    CheckIdle();
}

public void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, object e)
{
    dispatcherTimer.Tick -= dispatcherTimer_Tick;
    dispatcherTimer.Stop();
    Frame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage));
}

private void CheckIdle()
{
    //Calling DispatcherTimer.Start() will reset the timer interval
    Window.Current.CoreWindow.PointerMoved += (s, e) => dispatcherTimer.Start();
    Window.Current.CoreWindow.PointerPressed += (s, e) => dispatcherTimer.Start();
    Window.Current.CoreWindow.PointerReleased += (s, e) => dispatcherTimer.Start();
    Window.Current.CoreWindow.PointerWheelChanged += (s, e) => dispatcherTimer.Start();
    Window.Current.CoreWindow.KeyDown += (s, e) => dispatcherTimer.Start();
    Window.Current.CoreWindow.KeyUp += (s, e) => dispatcherTimer.Start();
    Window.Current.CoreWindow.CharacterReceived += (s, e) => dispatcherTimer.Start();
}
```

Comment: It appears you didn't handle the inactivity requirement.

Comment: @mason What do you mean by "inactivity requirement"?

Comment: It should only navigate back to the home page if there has been no activity.

Comment: @mason He didn't mention it in his question.

Comment: What do you  think is meant by "inactivity counter"?

Comment: @mason Ya, Dam. I missed it. I will update my answer. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: That's better. I would add an explanation that calling DispatcherTimer.Start will reset the timer interval.

Comment: @mason I have added the explanation.